# CRUD app in reactjs only

Tags: reactjs

Hello ReactJS Developer,
I want to ask that, is it possible to create CRUD app in ReactJS only without Redux and any other technology. Because ReactJS is V in MVC and how can is it possible to create CRUD app without Model and Controller.

**Thanks in Advance**

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is absolutely possible. Imho it's a valid optios for quick prototypes only, and makes your code not elegant at all, but it's possible.
What you would do is calling network requests bound to certain events, or bound to the page load, and updating the component state via `this.setState()`.
One of the things that redux accomplishes out of the box for you is provide access to the global store from whichever component you like.
Without redux, you are in charge of manually passing the interesting data to children components via props.

Comment: **Thanks for Reply**

Comment: Np, do you need more details?

Comment: Yes... I start react two days ago.. I want to ask which tutorial is best for me to learn react like you...

Comment: Check out ReactJS courses created by this author, he helped me a lot years ago
https://www.pluralsight.com/authors/cory-house. Also, don't be afraid to read the docs and the source code

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I do this. It is very simple. Need to just work with array to create CRUD App in reactJS. Just Need to use, array functions like, pop(), splice(), unshift(), push() and need some knowledge of CSS